# Asterisk, GSM-FXO gateway example of usage

Tags: asterisk, voip

Can anyone explain where to use  GSM-FXO gateway. I understand where to use GSM-FXS - for example to connect analogue telephone to gsm gateway. But do we use GSM-FXO to connect to two telephone stations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it in PBX on FXS port, also you can create an hot line using such gateway connected to a pstn. You just call a pstn number and got a call somewhere to gsm(operator's phone)